# How to use poll/epoll with GLFW events polling

Tags: linux, glfw, epoll

I need to use `epoll` on top of the `GLFW` event polling. My first try was to add `X11` socket descriptor to the `epoll` and wait on events. If the descriptor becomes readable, I used `glfwPollEvents()` to drain `X11` events.

But, to my surprise, the `X11` file descriptor are readable all the time, which creates busy loop.

The question is, how to use `GLFW` event polling with some outer event polling interface.

Answer (score 0):

Since `glfwPollEvents`, `poll` and `epoll_wait` are non-blocking (for `poll` and `epoll` if `timeout` is set to zero), why not call them in sequence. GLFW will handle the X11 Events, while `poll` or `epoll_wait` will handle the IO Events,

e.g.

```
while (active) {
    glfwPollEvents();   //handle queued only display events
    epoll_wait(..., 0); //handle io events
    nanosleep(...);     //instead of sleep, 
                        //use the timeout functionality 
                        //of the addressed functions (e.g. glfwWaitEventsTimeout)
}
```

If you have to populate an event queue with your own event structures, build them in the event handlers and push them onto the queue. If you call glfw and poll in sequence, there will be no danger of any asynchronicity.

Comment: The issue here, is that I want `epoll_wait` to block until some events arrive on X11 socket. For now, I use one and only X11 socket. And, as I stated in the question, epoll_wait wakeups with some data *after* `glfwPollEvents()` gets called.

Comment: `glfwWaitEvents` blocks until at least one event is available in the event queue. You already have that functionality, so why do you want to use `epoll_wait`? If you don't want to use glfw, `XPending` lets you poll the number of events and `XNextEvent` lets you wait until an event arrives. If all of the above is not what you want, then you have to deal with what `epoll_wait` does (what it is supposed to do).

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/libevdev/ (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evdev)

Comment: "`glfwWaitEvents` blocks until at least one event is avaible" - it blocks waiting for the X11 and glfw events.

Comment: "_at least **one** event_", yes, and?

Comment: it does not wait, or able to wait on file descriptors.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/685